# Deleting item from ListView and Database with OnItemClickListener

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-sqlite

I created a database and managed to display the added items into a ListView. Now I need a method to delete an item from the ListView and the Database.

```
public class ZeigeFaecherListe extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHelper myDb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.zeige_faecher);

        myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        ListView listViewFaecher = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewFaecher);

        final ArrayList<String> faecherListe = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor res = myDb.zeigeFaecher();

        if (res.getCount() == 0){
            Toast.makeText(ZeigeFaecherListe.this, "Keine Fächer gefunden", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            while (res.moveToNext()){
                faecherListe.add(res.getString(1));
                ListAdapter fachListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, faecherListe);
                listViewFaecher.setAdapter(fachListAdapter);
            }
        }

        listViewFaecher.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: No. You need a method to delete the item from the database and THEN update the ListView accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, but i need a way to choose the item with the listview and i dont know how to implement this.

Comment: see the last parameter passed to `onItemClick` method

Comment: You have the `id` parameter, which is there for that.

Comment: How does the user delete an item? Just by clicking on it? Or do they have to select it and then press a delete button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you need to be able to distinguish a row for deletion by the data available to the ListView. If the value retrieved from the cursor, as the 2nd column (i.e. the String extracted by using `res.getString(1))`, **and the value is going the be unique**, you can retrieve this and use it for the deletion.

However, there are a few issues, using a `ListAdapter` will probably not be sufficient. There are other adapters, such as an ArrayAdapter that offer more features and importantly a **`notifyDatasetChanged`** method (that will refresh the associated ListView).

It is a waste to create a new adapter for each iteration of the cursor. So the adapter should be created outside of the loop and just the once.

I'd suggest that deleting on item click will be too prone to accidental clicking, deleting on item LongClick would be far less prone to accidental deletion.

If you move variables to be class variables you don't have to declare them as final.

So based upon the above, you could have :-

### Array Adapter method

```
public class ZeigeFaecherListe extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHelper myDb;
    Cursor res;
    ListView listViewFaecher;
    ArrayAdapter<String> fachListAdapter;
    ArrayList<String> faecherListe;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.zeige_faecher);

        listViewFaecher = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.listview);
        myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        addSomeData(); //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED for testing

        faecherListe = new ArrayList<>();
        res = myDb.zeigeFaecher();
        while (res.moveToNext()) {
            faecherListe.add(res.getString(1));
        }

        //<<<< NOTE outside of the loop as this only needs to be done once
        fachListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                faecherListe
        );
        listViewFaecher.setAdapter(fachListAdapter);

        //<<<<< NOTE used LONG CLICK listener (less likely to accidentally delete)
        listViewFaecher.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                myDb.deleteRow((String)fachListAdapter.getItem(position));
                faecherListe.remove(position);
                fachListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
                return true; //<<<< Indicate that this longclick has been used
            }
        });
    }

    private void addSomeData() {
        for (int i=1; i <= 10; i++) {
            myDb.addRow("Row " + String.valueOf(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Along with the above the **`deletRow`** method is :-

```
public int deleteRow(String col2) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete(TB001,COL_TB001_DATA + "=?",new String[]{col2});
}
```

- where

  - **TB001** is a constant String thatis set to the table's name.
  - **COL_TB001_DATA** is the column name of the 2nd column.

**WARNING** The solution above will only work correctly if the 2nd column contains unique data, otherwise multiple rows would be deleted.

There is also the assumption that the deletion works, it could be better to have :-

```
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (myDb.deleteRow((String)fachListAdapter.getItem(position))<0) {
                faecherListe.remove(position);
            }
            fachListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
            return true; //<<<< Indicate that this longclick has been used
        }
```

### Cursor Adapter method

However, there are other adaptors suited to Cursors that could do away with the need for an intermediate Array. You could utilise a **`CursorAdapter`**. For a **`CursorAdapter`** a column name **`_id`** is required and this column should be a **long** and also unqiuely identify the row. The intention and hence the name is that an alias of the **rowid** is used (hence also why the CONSTANT **`BaseColumns._ID`** exists).

An alias of the **rowid** is created by defining `?? INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` where ?? is the column name. So ideally the table should be defined including a column definition with  `_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`  e.g. `CREATE mytable (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, myothercolumn TEXT)` *(you can follow `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` with the keyword AUTOINCREMENT, however generally you would not do so, as it has overheads [SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html))*

If your table does not have such a column then you can always create a column in the cursor when querying the data, by using `rowid AS _id` e.g. if you SQL equates to `SELECT * FROM mytable`  then you can use `SELECT *, rowid AS _id FROM mytable`.

In this example the stock **`SimpleCursorAdapter`** will be used, the code could be :-

```
public class ZeigeFaecherListe extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHelper myDb;
    Cursor res;
    ListView listViewFaecher;
    SimpleCursorAdapter fachSimpleCursorAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.zeige_faecher);

        listViewFaecher = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.listview);
        myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        addSomeData(); //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED for testing

        faecherListe = new ArrayList<>();
        res = myDb.zeigeFaecher();
        fachSimpleCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, //<<<< The layout
                res, //<<<< The Cursor
                new String[]{"_data"}, //<<<< The column names from which to get the data
                new int[]{android.R.id.text1} //<<<< The ids of the views in which the data is placed
                );
        listViewFaecher.setAdapter(fachSimpleCursorAdapter);
        listViewFaecher.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // id is the value of the respective _id column
                //<<<< Normally you would have the delete method in the Databasehelper >>>>
                myDb.getWritableDatabase().delete("mytable","_id=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
                fachSimpleCursorAdapter.swapCursor(myDb.zeigeFaecher()); // Tell the adapter about the new cursor
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**NOTE** as the **`_id`** column will always be unique this method will only delete the specific row not multiple rows if the displayed values are not unique.

Answer (score -1):

```
listViewFaecher.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

         // Call delete method here by passing position
         //position will contain the position of item clicked by the user.
     }
});
```