# SQLite Database item comes back after restarting Activity even though it was deleted

Tags: android, sqlite, android-activity

On deleting the item from the Listview the item gets deleted at that time, but on coming back to the activity the item reappears. 
This is my Main2Activity code:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
position = intent.getIntExtra("position", 0);
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,  listItem);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
viewData1();
 listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int pos, long id) {


            final int itemToDelete = pos;

            new AlertDialog.Builder(Main2Activity.this)
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .setTitle("Are you sure?")
                    .setMessage("Do you want to delete this location?")
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                    listItem.remove(itemToDelete);
                                    databaseHelper1.deleteLocation(itemToDelete, position);


                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                }


                            }
                    )
                    .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                    .show();

            return true;
        }

    });
}

private void viewData1() {

    Cursor cursor = databaseHelper1.viewData1(position);

    if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "No data to show", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            Log.i("message", "Data got");

            listItem.add(cursor.getString(1));
        }

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

DatabaseHelper:

```
public void deleteLocation(int itemToDelete,int position)
{
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();

    String itemDelete = Integer.toString(itemToDelete);

    Log.i("itemdel",itemDelete);

    if(position ==0)
    {
        String Id = (ID1);
        Log.i("Id",Id);
        String query =  " Delete from "+DB_TABLE1 + " where "+ Id + " = " + itemDelete;
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(query);
        sqLiteDatabase.delete(DB_TABLE1,ID1 + " = "+ itemDelete, null);
        sqLiteDatabase.compileStatement(query);

        Log.i("del"," executed")

    }

}

public Cursor viewData1(int position)
{
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = null;

    if (position ==0)
    {

        String query = "Select * from " + DB_TABLE1;
        cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);
    }
return cursor;
}
```

What happens is:
Before Deleting:

[image]

After Deleting garden:

[image]

On restarting activity:

[image]

How do I commit the delete to the database? Thanks.

Comment: you are performing database deletion operation if the position 0 `if(position ==0)` only. Here is that issue.

Comment: 'pos' denotes the position which will get deleted while 'position' is my activity intent number. @RakeshKumar

Comment: @Navdik, Yes it will be deleted as you are getting that from previous `activity`. But `Sqlite` query will perform an action only if that `position=0`. Check your position in `Log`. If not 0 then it won't delete from `db`.

Comment: I have specified the 'position=0' condition because it is unique to the Main2Activity. Other activities are present having  their unique  'position' . 'pos' on the other hand is the item long clicked. If the item  is clicked it deletes only for the period that I am still on that activity irrespective of the 'pos' @RakeshKumar

Comment: are you able to reach on that condition and also put try and catch block on that delete query and will get an exception and then able to help.

Comment: try this query `sqLiteDatabase.delete(yourTableName, "yourColumnName" + "=?",new String[]{value});`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are assuming that position (3rd parameter passed to the onItemLongClick method) directly relates to the id of the row.

You cannot rely on a correlation between position and id.

The first position in the list will be at position 0. The lowest ID allocated (unless forced) will be 1. However adding 1 is not a solution as even though it may initially work. As soon as you delete anything other than the last item in the list then an **id** is omitted from the list of id's and you may not delete a row or you may delete a different row.

The most sensible/easiest fix is to utilise a CursorAdapter i.e. SimpleCursorAdapter in which case the 4th parameter to **onItemClick** and **onItemLongClick** (long l) will be the actual **id**. However, to utilise a CursorAdapter you MUST have the id column named as **_id** (hence why there is the constant *BaseColumns._ID*).

You could always rename the column when extracting it using AS e.g. `SELECT rowid AS _id, * FROM the_table;` (which will select all existing columns AND the id column).

Here's a link to a more comprehensive answer with options for other adapter [Deleting item from ListView and Database with OnItemClickListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50775159/deleting-item-from-listview-and-database-with-onitemclicklistener/50778490#50778490)