# Android Studio Sqllite autoincrement reset

Tags: java, android, sqlite

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " +DBTable0+ "("+ROW2+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+ROW3+" VARCHAR NOT NULL, "+ROW0+" TEXT NOT NULL, "+ROW1+" VARCHAR NOT NULL)");
```

Here is my datebase's create table command.

I want to reset ROW2's values.

For Example i have 5 record on this table.

> 1, save1, This is a Save1, 11.25
>
> 2, save2, This is a Save2, 23.48
>
> 3, save3, This is a Save3, 09.45
>
> 4, save4, This is a Save4, 11.55
>
> 5, save5, This is a Save5, 21.00

I want to delete save2. When i delete it or other delete i want to reset ROW2 indexes, so

> 1, save1, This is a Save1, 11.25
>
> 2, save3, This is a Save3, 09.45
>
> 3, save4, This is a Save4, 11.55
>
> 4, save5, This is a Save5, 21.00

Like this ...

How i can do it .?

Comment: **Never mess with the auto-increment value!**

Comment: Why do you want to change the IDs? What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: This Records showing in the ListView.

Comment: I'll select the records via ListViews. Then i can delete and update the records on i selected item. So when i delete any records in the middless. the id's are mixing and deleting false records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reset the **rowid** assigned to compensate for deleted row's when AUTOINCREMENT is used you have to make two changes:-

1. You would have to alter (UPDATE) the **rowid** or an alias of the **rowid** of each row that is out of sequence to following the new sequence and
2. then you would have to alter (UPDATE) the respective row in the system table **sqlite_sequence** to the highest **rowid** allocated.

**This is not at all advisable and will greatly compound the inefficiencies of using AUTOINCREMENT** (when there is a very good chance that you do not need to use AUTOINCREMENT).

- [SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html) includes
- > The AUTOINCREMENT keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and disk I/O overhead and **should be avoided if not strictly needed. It is usually not needed.**

***In fact it is inadvisable to ever rely upon the* `rowid` *being anything other than what SQlite assigns***

- (`<column_name> INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` (with or without AUTOINCREMENT) makes <column_name> and alias of the **rowid**).

###You say :-

> **I want to reset ROW2's values.**

I would suggest re-evaluating your want to only wanting this if there is in fact a need, which in all likliehood, there isn't.

###You then say

> I'll select the records via ListViews. Then i can delete and update the records on i selected item. So when i delete any records in the middless. the id's are mixing and deleting false records

If you use a CursorAdapter, e.g. SimpleCursorAdapter, the 4th parameter of onItemClick and onItemLongClick is the **id**.

Noting that to use a CursorAdapter a column named **_id** must be present in the Cursor that is the source of the ListView and that column should contain the **rowid**. You can use **BaseColumns._ID**, which is a constant that has the value **_id**.

Generally you'd define the column in the table to be `_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`

Alternately you could use `rowid AS _id, *` in which case the column **_id** would be additional to all the other columns.

this and other options/explantions for other adapters can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50775159/deleting-item-from-listview-and-database-with-onitemclicklistener/50778490#50778490)

##Working Example

However, if you insist then the following example does what I believe you are asking.

**Note** this example does the same (*effectively*) for 2 tables.

- The first table **table1** uses AUTOINCREMENT
- The second table **table2** doesn't have AUTOINCREMENT coded but the results are identical (other than sqlite_sequence is not amended as there is no need as there is no row in sqlite_sequence due to AUTOINCREMENT nor being coded).

The main code is in the Database Helper (subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper) namely **DBHelper.java** :-

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "mydb";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;

    public static final String TBL_TABLE1 = "table1";
    public static final String TBL_TABLE2 = "table2";
    public static final String COL_TABLE_COL1 = "col1";
    public static final String COL_TABLE_COL2 = "col2";
    public static final String COL_TABLE_COL3 = "col3";

    private static final String crt_table1_sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TBL_TABLE1 + "(" +
            COL_TABLE_COL1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            COL_TABLE_COL2 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            COL_TABLE_COL3 + " TEXT NOT NULL" +
            ")";
    private static final String crt_table2_sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TBL_TABLE2 + "(" +
            COL_TABLE_COL1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
            COL_TABLE_COL2 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            COL_TABLE_COL3 + " TEXT NOT NULL" +
            ")";

    SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onConfigure(db);
        db.disableWriteAheadLogging();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(crt_table1_sql);
        db.execSQL(crt_table2_sql);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {

    }

    public void insert(String col2, String col3) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_TABLE_COL2,col2);
        cv.put(COL_TABLE_COL3,col3);
        mDB.beginTransaction();
        mDB.insert(TBL_TABLE1,null,cv);
        mDB.insert(TBL_TABLE2,null,cv);
        mDB.setTransactionSuccessful();
        mDB.endTransaction();
    }

    public void deleteByValues(String col2, String col3) {
        String whereclause = COL_TABLE_COL2 + "=? AND " + COL_TABLE_COL3 + "=?";
        String[] args = new String[]{col2,col3};
        mDB.beginTransaction();
        mDB.delete(TBL_TABLE1,whereclause,args);
        mDB.delete(TBL_TABLE2,whereclause,args);
        rationaliseCol1Values();
        mDB.setTransactionSuccessful();
        mDB.endTransaction();
    }

    private void rationaliseCol1Values() {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        Cursor csr = mDB.query(TBL_TABLE1,null,null,null,null,null,COL_TABLE_COL1 + " ASC");

        int rowcount = csr.getCount();
        long expected_id = 1;
        long current_id;
        String where_clause = COL_TABLE_COL1 + "=?";
        String[] args = new String[1];

        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            current_id = csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_TABLE_COL1));
            if (current_id != expected_id) {
                cv.clear();
                cv.put(COL_TABLE_COL1,expected_id);
                args[0] = String.valueOf(current_id);
                mDB.update(TBL_TABLE1,cv,where_clause,args);
                mDB.update(TBL_TABLE2,cv,where_clause,args);
            }
            expected_id++;
        }
        csr.close();
        // Now adjust sqlite_sequence
        where_clause = "name=?";
        args[0] = TBL_TABLE1;
        cv.clear();
        cv.put("seq",String.valueOf(rowcount));
        mDB.update("sqlite_sequence",cv,where_clause,args);
    }

    public void logTableRows(int stage) {

        String tablenamne_column = "tablename";    
        Cursor[] csr = new Cursor[] {
                mDB.query(TBL_TABLE1,new String[]{"'table1' AS " + tablenamne_column + ",*"},null,null,null,null,null),
                mDB.query(TBL_TABLE2,new String[]{"'table2' AS " + tablenamne_column + ",*"}, null,null,null,null,null)
        };
        MergeCursor csr3 = new MergeCursor(csr);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Data in both tables consists of " + String.valueOf(csr3.getCount()) + " rows :-");

        while (csr3.moveToNext()) {
            sb.append(
                    "\n\tTableName = " + csr3.getString(csr3.getColumnIndex(tablenamne_column)
                    )
            ).append(" " + COL_TABLE_COL1 + " value is " + csr3.getString(csr3.getColumnIndex(COL_TABLE_COL1))
            ).append(" " + COL_TABLE_COL2 + " value is " + csr3.getString(csr3.getColumnIndex(COL_TABLE_COL2))
            ).append(" " + COL_TABLE_COL3 + " value is" + csr3.getString(csr3.getColumnIndex(COL_TABLE_COL3))
            );
        }
        Log.d("DATA4STAGE" + String.valueOf(stage),sb.toString());
    }
}
```

- The core manipulation of the **rowid** (alias therefore i.e. **COL1**) is undertaken by the **rationaliseCol1Values()** method. This itself is invoked as part of the **deleteByValues** method.

  - if there were a method to delete according to **id** aka **COL1** then this too would invoke the **rationaliseCol1Values()** method).
- The **logTableRows** just exists so that the tables can be output to the log.

The invoking activity used for testing the above was :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DBHelper mDBHlpr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDBHlpr = new DBHelper(this);
        manipulateSomeData();
    }

    private void manipulateSomeData() {
        mDBHlpr.logTableRows(0);
        mDBHlpr.insert("TEST001","TESTING001");
        mDBHlpr.insert("TEST002","TESTING001");
        mDBHlpr.insert("TEST003","TESTING001");
        mDBHlpr.insert("TEST004","TESTING001");
        mDBHlpr.insert("TEST005","TESTING001");
        mDBHlpr.insert("TEST006","TESTING001");
        mDBHlpr.insert("TEST007","TESTING001");
        mDBHlpr.insert("TEST008","TESTING001");
        mDBHlpr.insert("TEST009","TESTING001");
        mDBHlpr.logTableRows(1);

        mDBHlpr.deleteByValues("TEST005","TESTING001");
        mDBHlpr.logTableRows(2);
        mDBHlpr.deleteByValues("TEST008","TESTING001");
        mDBHlpr.logTableRows(3);
        mDBHlpr.deleteByValues("TEST003","TESTIN001");
        mDBHlpr.logTableRows(4);
    }
}
```

- This :-

  1. lists the rows (none when first run).
  2. Adds 9 rows with COL2 being unique (again only when first run).
  3. list all the 9 rows (1st run).
  4. deletes any rows that have values "TEST005" in COL2 **AND** "TESTING001" in COL3.
  5. lists the rows (note how COL1's sequence is maintained).
  6. deletes any rows that have values "TEST008" in COL2 **AND** "TESTING001" in COL3.

1. lists the rows (note how COL1's sequence is maintained).
2. deletes any rows that have values "TEST003" in COL2 **AND** "TESTIN001" in COL3. ***None do due to the typo (missing G)***
3. lists the rows (note how COL1's sequence is maintained).

The Results output to the log being :-

```
2018-12-31 12:43:21.618 2269-2269/so53976714.so53976714 D/DATA4STAGE0: Data in both tables consists of 0 rows :-
2018-12-31 12:43:21.657 2269-2269/so53976714.so53976714 D/DATA4STAGE1: Data in both tables consists of 18 rows :-
        TableName = table1 col1 value is 1 col2 value is TEST001 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table1 col1 value is 2 col2 value is TEST002 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table1 col1 value is 3 col2 value is TEST003 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table1 col1 value is 4 col2 value is TEST004 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table1 col1 value is 5 col2 value is TEST005 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table1 col1 value is 6 col2 value is TEST006 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table1 col1 value is 7 col2 value is TEST007 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table1 col1 value is 8 col2 value is TEST008 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table1 col1 value is 9 col2 value is TEST009 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table2 col1 value is 1 col2 value is TEST001 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table2 col1 value is 2 col2 value is TEST002 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table2 col1 value is 3 col2 value is TEST003 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table2 col1 value is 4 col2 value is TEST004 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table2 col1 value is 5 col2 value is TEST005 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table2 col1 value is 6 col2 value is TEST006 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table2 col1 value is 7 col2 value is TEST007 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table2 col1 value is 8 col2 value is TEST008 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table2 col1 value is 9 col2 value is TEST009 col3 value isTESTING001
2018-12-31 12:43:21.666 2269-2269/so53976714.so53976714 D/DATA4STAGE2: Data in both tables consists of 16 rows :-
        TableName = table1 col1 value is 1 col2 value is TEST001 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table1 col1 value is 2 col2 value is TEST002 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table1 col1 value is 3 col2 value is TEST003 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table1 col1 value is 4 col2 value is TEST004 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table1 col1 value is 5 col2 value is TEST006 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table1 col1 value is 6 col2 value is TEST007 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table1 col1 value is 7 col2 value is TEST008 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table1 col1 value is 8 col2 value is TEST009 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table2 col1 value is 1 col2 value is TEST001 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table2 col1 value is 2 col2 value is TEST002 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table2 col1 value is 3 col2 value is TEST003 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table2 col1 value is 4 col2 value is TEST004 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table2 col1 value is 5 col2 value is TEST006 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table2 col1 value is 6 col2 value is TEST007 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table2 col1 value is 7 col2 value is TEST008 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table2 col1 value is 8 col2 value is TEST009 col3 value isTESTING001
2018-12-31 12:43:21.675 2269-2269/so53976714.so53976714 D/DATA4STAGE3: Data in both tables consists of 14 rows :-
        TableName = table1 col1 value is 1 col2 value is TEST001 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table1 col1 value is 2 col2 value is TEST002 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table1 col1 value is 3 col2 value is TEST003 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table1 col1 value is 4 col2 value is TEST004 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table1 col1 value is 5 col2 value is TEST006 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table1 col1 value is 6 col2 value is TEST007 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table1 col1 value is 7 col2 value is TEST009 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table2 col1 value is 1 col2 value is TEST001 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table2 col1 value is 2 col2 value is TEST002 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table2 col1 value is 3 col2 value is TEST003 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table2 col1 value is 4 col2 value is TEST004 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table2 col1 value is 5 col2 value is TEST006 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table2 col1 value is 6 col2 value is TEST007 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table2 col1 value is 7 col2 value is TEST009 col3 value isTESTING001
2018-12-31 12:43:21.681 2269-2269/so53976714.so53976714 D/DATA4STAGE4: Data in both tables consists of 14 rows :-
        TableName = table1 col1 value is 1 col2 value is TEST001 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table1 col1 value is 2 col2 value is TEST002 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table1 col1 value is 3 col2 value is TEST003 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table1 col1 value is 4 col2 value is TEST004 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table1 col1 value is 5 col2 value is TEST006 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table1 col1 value is 6 col2 value is TEST007 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table1 col1 value is 7 col2 value is TEST009 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table2 col1 value is 1 col2 value is TEST001 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table2 col1 value is 2 col2 value is TEST002 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table2 col1 value is 3 col2 value is TEST003 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table2 col1 value is 4 col2 value is TEST004 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table2 col1 value is 5 col2 value is TEST006 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table2 col1 value is 6 col2 value is TEST007 col3 value isTESTING001
        TableName = table2 col1 value is 7 col2 value is TEST009 col3 value isTESTING001
```

#NOTE using the above is NOT recommended

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of the `AUTOINCREMENT` keyword is to never re-use a rowid. It stores the highest assigned one for a table, and when inserting a new row that doesn't have a rowid explicitly given in the insert statement, picks a number higher than that stored one. Without `AUTOINCREMENT`, it just chooses a number higher than the current maximum rowid in the table (And if the maximum is the largest possible signed 64-bit integer, it picks a few smaller ones at random hoping for a missing one before giving up).

If you want to recycle rowid numbers, you either have to find the missing ones manually and use them explicitly in `UPDATE` statements, or not have an `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` column, and run `VACUUM` after deleting rows. Without the `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` column aliasing the rowid, sqlite will rearrange them in that case. Or you could copy the table's rows, minus the `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` column, into a new table to get new rowids. All of these are horribly inefficient approaches and not desirable. Live with gaps from deleted rows.

Mandatory reading to understand rowid, `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` columns, and `AUTOINCREMENT`:

https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html

https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid

https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

> I'll select the records via ListViews. Then i can delete and update the records on i selected item. So when i delete any records in the middless. the id's are mixing and deleting false records

Sounds like you're assuming something's position a list is the same as a row's rowid? No wonder you're having problems. Keep explicit track of the rowid and use that when deleting the requested data. Classic case of an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE "  +ACT.DBTable0+ " DROP " +ACT.ROW2);
                db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " +ACT.DBTable0+ " ADD " +ACT.ROW2+ " PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT");

Comment: @CrossV4 Um... no. You can't drop columns from a table.

Comment: Addendum: As of Sqlite 3.35.0 `ALTER TABLE` does support dropping columns, but not if it's a primary key or a bunch of other cases.